# Getting Started with google maps API, displaying a community

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to immerse myself into the Google Maps API to display some locations on a website. I have looked through the official documentation found here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial However, I am a visual learner, and have a lot more success working through tutorials hands on.

My objective for now is very simple, I just would like to display a sub locality (that is already within google maps, i.e. https://www.google.com/maps/preview?authuser=0#!q=Greenfield+Lakes%2C+Gilbert%2C+AZ+sub+locality&data=!1m4!1m3!1d33995!2d-111.7348491!3d33.3303003!4m10!1m9!4m8!1m3!1d4249!2d-111.736458!3d33.338736!3m2!1i1920!2i979!4f13.1 and display that on my own website.

Does anyone have any recommendations on how to start this process or know of a tutorial that could help me on my way?

Answer (score 0):

i have implemented same with google maps. may be this will give you some idea [**Google Maps implementation**](http://www.harshabopuri.com/onclick-dynamic-google-maps-in-website)

also answered similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/a/7894821/942855

Comment: I am having a little trouble with the implementation (I believe it is because I am not using the same platform. Could you adjust format to fit LAMP stack (WordPress)?

Comment: get a google maps API and change the API reference here http://jsfiddle.net/habo/MzFDM/